# Creating a simulation of a bidding game on Geogebra

Tags: simulation

Alice, Bob, and Charlie are chosen to participate in an auction for an economics class.
Each submits a secret bid of 1, 2, or 3. The person with the lowest and unique* bid wins the auction and gets a prize of $1.
*Example: If Alice and Bob bid 1, and Charlie bids 2, then Charlie wins. Although Alice and Bob bid lower numbers, their bids were not unique so they do not win.
(Also: if they all bid the same number, no one wins)

I'm studying this problem in class, and I've been asked to create a simulation where for each person I choose the probabilities they will play either 1, 2, or 3 (for example I would set Alice to play 1 80% of the time, and 2 and 3 10% of the time each, Bob would do something else, and Charlie would play with different probabilities) and then run a bunch of simulations and see which person won the most. How would I create such a simulation?

Comment: Is there a particular language or system that you're to use for this assignment?

Comment: Whoops! I missed the reference to GeoGebra...

Answer (score 0):

The solution should be fairly simple.

Firstly, you will need to know how to cast a bid for a player. We'll represent the probabilities of each bid using an array, such that the sum of values is `1.0`, and each bidder will have their own array. The first array element is the probability of bidding 1, the second, the probability of bidding 2, etc.

The next step is to convert this probability array into an array of *cumulative probabilities*, for calculating the probability that a bid value is less than or equal to a specified number. In this new array, the first array element is the probability of bidding 1, the second is the probability of bidding 1 or 2, the last element is the probability of bidding 1, 2 or 3 (and should have the value `1.0`). Although it's redundant to include this latter value, it will simplify the algorithm.

Next we need to have multiple bidding rounds. In each round, we need to randomly determine a bid value for each player. To do this, we sample a *uniformly-distributed pseudo-random number* (*PRN*) in the range `[0, 1)`. Fortunately, most programming languages, systems, etc. provide such a capability. We then loop through the cumulative probability array until we find a cumulative probability that is greater than a sampled *PRN* - the bid is then the corresponding array index.

We repeat that for each bidder.

Next, we filter out non-unique bids. We then take the lowest remaining bid (if any) and increment the number of wins for the associated bidder.

This process is then repeated until we get stable percentages for each player's win rate. (By stable, I mean that each new round of bidding should not significantly affect the win percentages for each bidder.)

Comment: It's not _[GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/)_, but I've posted a _Scala_ command line program on _[GitHub](https://github.com/MichaelJAllen/BidSim)_ that performs this simulation.